# Apache Spark: how to do a distinct count and count together?

Tags: apache-spark

I would like to do a distinct count and a count at the same time.
Let me explain you through a simple example.
Here is my input data:

```
arbre;pommier
fruit;pomme
fruit;pomme
fruit;fraise
fruit;ichigo
arbre;cerisier
arbre;abricotier
sport;foot
sport;rugby
arbre;abricotier
arbre;abricotier
arbre;bananier
fruit;ananas
sport;basket
arbre;abricotier
arbre;abricotier
```

As an output, I want to get that:

```
//type;count;distinct-count
arbre;9;3
fruit;5;4
sport;3;3
```

With the word count example, I can compute the number of time a word appears (so here is count). And with the function `distinct().groupeByKey()`, I manage to compute the distinct count (here is distinct-count).

However, I can't figure out how to do that on the same RDD and not two separate RDDs.

If you have an idea, documentation or a link about this subject I would be very thankful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Data:

```
col1,col2
arbre,pommier
fruit,pomme
fruit,pomme
fruit,fraise
fruit,ichigo
arbre,cerisier
arbre,abricotier
sport,foot
sport,rugby
arbre,abricotier
arbre,abricotier
arbre,bananier
fruit,ananas
sport,basket
arbre,abricotier
arbre,abricotier
```

Creating Dataframe using **Spark 2**

```
val df = sqlContext.read.option("header", "true").option("inferSchema", "true").csv("filelocation")

df.show

import sqlContext.implicits._

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

//Applying count and distinct count
df.groupBy("col1")
  .agg(count("col2").alias("count"), countDistinct("col2").alias("distinct"))
  .show
```

Output:

```
+-----+-----+--------+
| col1|count|distinct|
+-----+-----+--------+
|arbre|    8|       4|
|sport|    3|       3|
|fruit|    5|       4|
+-----+-----+--------+
```

Comment: This is what i am looking for. Do you know how I can do that in Java ?

Comment: Futhermore, it seems that the result is not a rdd which I would like to have. am I right ?

Comment: The result is a dataframe, which can be converted to rdd using .rdd() function