# Get distinct count on two aggregations based on two different subsets of the data with group by

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Consider I have `Dataset<Row>` like this

```
Day User    isInstall   isPlayed
1   U1      1           1
1   U2      1           0
1   U3      0           1
1   U4      1           0
1   U4      1           1
2   U6      1           1
2   U7      1           0
2   U8      0           1
2   U8      0           1
2   U7      1           0
```

I want to group on Day field and get the count of unique users with isInstall as 1 & isPlayed as 1. Result should be like this :

```
Day    isInstallUU    isPlayedUU
1      3              3
2      2              2
```

I am able to get different dataset for isInstall & isPlayed counts like this, but I am confused how do I merge them and get one dataset.

```
Dataset<Row> result1 = responseDataset.filter(col("isInstall").equalTo(1))
    .groupBy("Day").agg(countDistinct("User").alias("isInstallUU"));

Dataset<Row> result2 = responseDataset.filter(col("isPlayed").equalTo(1))
    .groupBy("Day").agg(countDistinct("User").alias("isPlayedUU"));
```

How can I achieve this using java Spark APIs?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? If that can help you get started, there exists a `countDistinct` aggregation function in the `functions` class: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#countDistinct-org.apache.spark.sql.Column-org.apache.spark.sql.Column...-

Comment: This might be useful : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41148415/apache-spark-how-to-do-a-distinct-count-and-count-together/41155984

Comment: @Oli I have edited my post with what I have tried.

Comment: You can compute several aggregations at the same time `.agg(sum("col1"), sum("col2"), ...)`

Comment: @Oli Yes I can but the problem is I want to count distinct users when isInstall & isPlayed is 1. Please have a look at my example that might clear the scenario.

Comment: An easy way to do this would be to join `result1` and `result2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing it in one shot is a bit tricky (but doable with a bit of work) because you are computing aggregations on two different subsets of the data.

The easy way out is to compute two aggregations (as what you tried) and to join them:

```java
Dataset<Row> result1 = responseDataset
    .filter(col("isInstall").equalTo(1))
    .groupBy("Day")
    .agg(countDistinct("User").alias("isInstallUU"));

Dataset<Row> result2 = responseDataset
    .filter(col("isPlayed").equalTo(1))
    .groupBy("Day")
    .agg(countDistinct("User").alias("isPlayedUU"));

Dataset<Row> result = result1
    .join(result2, result1.col("Day").equalTo(result1.col("Day")), "full_outer")
    .na().fill(0);
```

Note that I use a full outer join because there might be users that do not appear in the two subsets. To avoid null values, I replace them with 0.

**EDIT**:

In case you are curious, there is a way to do it in one stage. The idea would be to create 2 additional user columns that are null when we do not want to aggregate them (spark ignores null values in `countDistinct`). It would look like this:

```java
Dataset<Row> result = responseDataset
    .withColumn("userI", when(col("isInstall").equalTo(1), col("user")))
    .withColumn("userP", when(col("isPlayed").equalTo(1), col("user")))
    .groupBy("day")
    .agg(countDistinct(col("userP")).alias("isPlayedUU"),
         countDistinct(col("userI")).alias("isInstallUU"));
```

Comment: Actually this is what I did when you mentioned in comments to join. Thanks a lot I am marking this answer as accepted.

Comment: My pleasure ;) And btw, I edited my answer to also provide a "one stage " answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the latest solution. This worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, filter the dataframe based on conditions provided by author. Then use group by to aggregate by "Day" column and append two new columns which represent distinct counts for Users.
Check below code:

```
    responseDataset.filter(col("isInstall").equalTo(1) && col("isPlayed").equalTo(1))
    .groupBy("Day")
    .agg(countDistinct("User").as("isInstallUU"), countDistinct("User").as("isPlayedUU"));
```

Comment: Firstly I filter dataframe based on conditions provided by author. Then use group by to aggregate by "Day" column and append two new columns which represent distinct counts for Users.

Comment: Unfortunately that does not work. You would miss all the users who have installed but not played and the one who have played but not installed. An "or" would not work either for that matter because we are interested in two aggregations based on two different subsets of the data.

Comment: @himanshu srivastava said that he wants to count distinct users when isInstall & isPlayed is 1